# How to manipulate transform: translate3d values with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I'm using the bxslider and I needed to modify it because there was no built in function for my purposes. But now I need to change the transform: translate3d values of the slider so that it will be displayed correctly. But how?

With using this syntax following error will occur:

```
$('#custom_pager_list').css({
    transform: translate3d(-400px, 0, 0)
})
```

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Using the same syntax without "px" leads to this:

> ReferenceError: translate3d is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the transform value:

```
$('#custom_pager_list').css({
    transform: "translate3d(-400px, 0, 0)"
})
```